# Why is the modifier .navigationBarTitle not applied to NavigationView?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I understand that modifiers are used to *modify* a view. When modifying a view, the modifier returns the view wrapped in `_ModifiedContent`.
When embedding my view inside a `NavigationView` and assigning a navigation bar title like this: (as seen in Apple's official tutorials)

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("My first SwiftUI App"))
}
```

...why is the modifier for the navigation bar title applied to `Text`, not to `NavigationView`?

Comment: It is documented: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3280165-navigationbartitle: “This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible within a NavigationView.”

Comment: Yes, I've read that but I feel like it doesn't make sense logically, considering the modifier modifies the view it's applied on and the nav bar title has literally *nothing* to do with the `Text` object.

Comment: You can even set it somewhere deeper in the view hierarchy (i.e. on a Spacer in a Toggle in a VStack ...) I have no idea why it works that way.

Answer (score 10):

Like Martin [linked to](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3280165-navigationbartitle), `navigationBarTitle` only works when contained in `NavigationView`. This is discussed briefly in the [SwiftUI Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/) talk at ~52:30. The title ends up flowing up to the `NavigationView`, so that views that get pushed can also provide a title of their own (e.g. the view that gets pushed at ~54:00).

If the title was attached to the `NavigationView` directly, all possible titles would need to be determined up front and removed from the views the titles are associated with.

It's similar to `UIViewController`'s `navigationItem` property, which is attached to each pushed view instead of the `UINavigationController` itself.

Answer (score 5):

Because the **`.navigationBarTitle()`** is modifier on the View inside of NavigationView, It is not on the NavigationView. And the same is the case for **`.navigationBarItem()`**.
Please refer to [Building Lists and Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation)